# 3 ips, 3 ports need to pick randomly and set to a variable - is this possible?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that connects to a shoutcast radio server however we have 3 servers which we need to random connect to, everything is set in a config file i.e

```
// ip or url of shoutcast server
$scip = "123.123.123.123";
// port of shoutcast server
$scport = "8026";
```

however i need to be able to set 3 ips and 3 related ports like example:

```
$serv_1 = '123.123.123.123';
$port_1 = '8026';
$serv_2 = '456.456.456.456';
$port_2 = '8702';
$serv_3 = '789.789.789.789';
$port_3 = '8026';
```

What i need to do is when page is loaded to select and ip and its related port at random and then set to the main scip and scport variables so that the listener will be on a randon shoutcast server and everything is not just set to 1 server

Im looking at doing this in PHP?

Comment: this seems like a simple task. what have you tried yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this...

```
$serv[1]['serv'] = '123.123.123.123';
$serv[1]['port'] = '8026';
$serv[2]['serv'] = '456.456.456.456';
$serv[2]['port'] = '8702';
$serv[3]['serv'] = '789.789.789.789';
$serv[3]['port'] = '8026';

$randNo = rand(1,3);
$randServ = $serv[$randNo]['serv'];
$randPort = $serv[$randNo]['port'];
```

Put the server and port in a multidimensional array, defining each with a unique number (1-3). Pick a number at random between 1 and 3 (`rand(1,3)`) and then use that number to grab random server & port.

Comment: Looks like it should work, but wouldn't you need to define the arrays before setting their values (`$serv=array(array(),array(),array())`), and shouldn't the array and rand be 0-based instead of 1-based?

Comment: It's really for the sake of readability it demonstrates the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
$servers=array("1.1.1.1:8026", "2.2.2.2:8702", "3.3.3.3:8026");
$server = $servers[array_rand($servers)];
$exploded = explode(":", $server);
$scip=$exploded[0];
$scport=$exploded[1];
```

Comment: i seem to get an error on this: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: php 5.4+ ;) replace the last 2 lines with: list( $scip, $scport ) = explode(':', $server);

Comment: i do list for each scip and scport?

Comment: I updated the answer. This should work even if you're not on 5.4 or newer.